# How to proof that $n^r<c^n$

Tags: analysis

I have to proof that:

$\forall r,c \in \Bbb R$ such that $r\ge 0$ and $c\gt 1$ we have:
$$\exists N\in \Bbb N, \forall n\ge N, n^r\lt c^n$$

As I am still struggling with mathematical proofs I wanted to ask if maybe someone could help me with this. I guess I have to do a Mathematical induction here.
I also think I have to do a case analysis here but I am not sure about it.

Comment: "I have to proof" $\to$ "I have to prove"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $f_n=\frac{n^r}{c^n}$. You need to prove that for large enough $n$ this is less than 1. Now consider $f_{n+1}/f_n$ and show that $\exists q<1$ that for large enough $n$ this quotient is less then $q$. That would mean that for large enough $n$ we have $f_{n+k}<f_n\cdot q^k$ for any natural $k$. Because of $q<1$, this $q^k$ kills $f_n$, no matter how large was it, for very large $k$, and then $f_{n+k}<1$.

Comment: @user406473 Note: the above is only a sketch of the proof, you should try to fulfill all necessary details - this is a useful exercise. If you fail to do some part, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n} {\log n}=\infty,$$there exists $N$ such that, for all $n\geq N$,$$ \frac{n} {\log n}>\frac r{\log c}.$$ This can be rewritten as $$r\log n<n\log c,$$ or $$\log n^r<\log c^n.$$ As the exponential is monotone increasing, your inequality follows.